# Removing a node From Doubly Threaded LnkLst

Tags: c++

Im trying to remove a single node from a doubly threaded linked list.

What I have works..Its just terribly inefficient.

I was wondering if I can get some expert advice or some while termination condition tips.

Here is the function in which I remove 1 node from a set of Rating Nodes, stored in headByRating and a set of Name nodes, stored in headByName. All of which are sorted....

```
bool list::remove (const char * const name)
{
    node *currByName     = headByName;
    node *currByRating   = headByRating;
    node *prev_node      = NULL;

    while ( NULL != currByName &&
          ( strcmp( name, currByName->item.getName() ) != 0 ) )
        {
            prev_node  = currByName;
            currByName = currByName->nextByName;
            prev_node->nextByName = currByName; 
        }

        if ( currByName == headByName )
        {   
            currByName   = currByName->nextByName;
            headByName   = currByName;
        }
            else if ( currByName->nextByName == NULL )
            {//then we must be at the end
                currByName = prev_node;
                currByName->nextByName = NULL;
                //return true;
            }
            else
            {
                currByName = prev_node;
                currByName->nextByName = currByName->nextByName->nextByName;
                //return true;
            }

    while ( NULL != currByRating && 
          ( strcmp( name, currByRating->item.getName() ) != 0 ) )
    {
        prev_node = currByRating;
        currByRating = currByRating->nextByRating;
        prev_node->nextByRating  = currByRating;
    }
        if ( currByRating == headByRating ) // was it the head?
        {
            currByRating = currByRating->nextByRating;
            headByRating = currByRating;
            return true;
        }
        else if ( currByRating->nextByRating == NULL ) // could it be the tail?
        {
            currByRating = prev_node;
            currByRating->nextByRating = NULL;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            currByRating = prev_node;
            currByRating->nextByRating = currByRating->nextByRating->nextByRating;
            return true;
        }


    return false;
}
```

Yeah i just need help simplifing the code, making it more efficient. I hoping to combine and use only one while loop if thats possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two choices:

1) Use a high level library that solves the problem.  [Boost MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) containers allow shared nodes with multiple ordered/mapped organizations.

2) Instead of two (sorted by rating and name) singly linked lists, use two doubly linked lists.  Then deletion of a given node is O(1).  To find a node quickly by name, you could use an efficient map (hash table or balanced tree).  If you don't mind scanning through one list to find the node, then that list doesn't need to be doubly linked.

As for deletion for linked lists, you're right to suspect that your code can be simplified immensely.  Either:

1) use a sentinel (dummy) node for the empty list; that way the "previous node" always exists for actual list items

2) instead of "pointer to previous node" in singly linked list deletion, store "pointer to "next pointer to this node"".

Here's what I mean by 2):

```
node **pn=&headByRating; // we will update headByRating=n via (*pn)=n if needed
node *c=*pn;  // we will have c == *pn except momentarily
while ( c && strcmp(name, c->item.getName()) {
    pn=&c->nextByRating; // c is now the previous node
    c=*pn; // c is *pn again
}
// now (*pn) points to the node we want to delete, i.e. c
*pn=c->next; // (*pn) skips right over c now.
// delete c; // or else you leak memory; you didn't specify how nodes are allocated
return true;
```

This should be equivalent to your:

```
while ( NULL != currByRating && 
      ( strcmp( name, currByRating->item.getName() ) != 0 ) )
{
    prev_node = currByRating;
    currByRating = currByRating->nextByRating;
    prev_node->nextByRating  = currByRating;
}
    if ( currByRating == headByRating ) // was it the head?
    {
        currByRating = currByRating->nextByRating;
        headByRating = currByRating;
        return true;
    }
    else if ( currByRating->nextByRating == NULL ) // could it be the tail?
    {
        currByRating = prev_node;
        currByRating->nextByRating = NULL;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        currByRating = prev_node;
        currByRating->nextByRating = currByRating->nextByRating->nextByRating;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: If it's homework (can't use Boost), then if you want it to be fast (skipping the second traversal), you need to use a doubly linked list for the second of the two orders.  You could also consider using a std::map or hash lookup to find the node by name instead of searching through a list.  My suggestion to simplify singly-linked list deletion won't make anything faster; it will just save code.

Comment: I've allocated nodes through an insertion sort "insort" function: node *current_node = new object( object_t ); where the object_t is being passed in for every node. I allocate each node with current_node.

Comment: Yes, it's equivalent (in what it does).  You shouldn't have to treat the "tail is NULL" case any differently.  And by using "node **pn" you don't have to treat "deleted node is head of list" differently.

Comment: Since you allocated all the nodes with new, make sure you delete them after the last use (uncomment my "delete c").

Answer (score 0):

It might be solved, but somehow I think I can do without two while loops..and redeclaring..

```
node **previous_node = &headByRating; // we will update headByRating via (*prev_node)=n if needed
    node *current_node   = *previous_node;  // we will have current == *prev_node except momentarily

    while ( current_node && strcmp( name, current_node->item.getName() ) != 0 ) 
    {
        previous_node = ¤t_node->nextByRating; // c is now the previous node
        current_node  = *previous_node; // current is *prev_node again
    }
        // now (*prev_node) points to the node we want to delete; current
        *previous_node = current_node->nextByRating; // (*prev_node) skips right over current now.

        node **prev_node = &headByName;
        node *cur_node   = *prev_node;

        while ( current_node && strcmp( name, cur_node->item.getName() ) != 0 )
        {
            prev_node = &cur_node->nextByName;
            cur_node = *prev_node;
        }

        *prev_node = cur_node->nextByName;

        delete current_node;// or else
        current_node = NULL; 

        return true;
}
```

I will study this =)
Thanks to wrang wrang for his exellence.